# Proof of the variational formulation of the nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

How to show that the nuclear norm can be written in the following way?

$$\|X\|_* = \min\limits_{A,B: AB=X}\frac{\|A\|^2_2}{2} + \frac{\|B\|^2_2}{2}$$

---

Related: [Variational characterization of nuclear norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1544623)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. E.g. when $n\ge2$,
$$
\|I_n\|_\ast
=n
>1
=\frac{\|I_n\|_2^2+\|I_n\|_2^2}{2}
\ge\min_{AB=I_n}\frac{\|A\|_2^2+\|B\|_2^2}{2} .
$$
The correct identity should have Frobenius norms instead of induced $2$-norms on the RHS. Let $U_0SV_0^\ast$ be a singular value decomposition of $X\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\|X\|_\ast
&=\|S\|_\ast\\
&=\frac{\|S^{1/2}\|_F^2+\|S^{1/2}\|_F^2}{2}\\
&=\frac{\|U_0S^{1/2}\|_F^2+\|S^{1/2}V_0^\ast\|_F^2}{2}\\
&\ge\inf_{AB=X}\frac{\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2}{2}\tag{1}\\
&\ge\inf_{AB=X}\|A\|_F\|B\|_F.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
However, for any pair of matrices $(A,B)$ with $AB=X$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|A\|_F\|B\|_F
&=\max_{U,V\in U(n)}\|A^\ast U\|_F\|BV\|_F\\
&\ge\max_{U,V\in U(n)}|\langle A^\ast U,BV\rangle_F|\\
&=\max_{U,V\in U(n)}|\operatorname{tr}(U^\ast ABV)|\\
&=\max_{U,V\in U(n)}|\operatorname{tr}(U^\ast XV)|\\
&=\|X\|_\ast .
\end{aligned}
$$
It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that
$$
\|X\|_\ast
=\inf_{AB=X}\frac{\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2}{2}
=\inf_{AB=X}\|A\|_F\|B\|_F.\tag{3}
$$
Two infima in $(3)$ are actually minima and they are attained by $(A,B)=(U_0S^{1/2},\,S^{1/2}V_0^\ast)$.